# xss-lock, loginctl lock-sessions, xsecurelock not working together on Arch

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xorg, session-manager

I have xsecurelock installed on arch, and I can lock the session by running `xsecure lock`. Trying to lock with `loginctl lock-session` does nothing, though (no error, just no output, and no locking).

From the research I've done, `loginctl lock-session` is is presumably calling `xss-lock`, but I can't see how to configure xss-lock to know that it should use xsecurelock as the locker.

Running `xss-lock` complains about no locker being specified, and running `xss-lock xsecurelock` just hangs.

Answer (score 2):

> running xss-lock xsecurelock just hangs.

Yes, that's what it is supposed to do.

The entire point of `loginctl lock-session[s]` is that it doesn't *run* anything directly; instead it broadcasts a "Lock" signal to programs which are already running within your desktop session – basically telling the desktop environment to lock itself. (This neatly avoids all "missing environment variable" problems that you would have when trying to start a locker externally.)

So "xss-lock" is meant to be permanently running as a background process – a daemon, only at session level, not at system level. You can start it from your ~/.xprofile using `&` for background, or you can start it from your window manager's "autorun" settings (almost all WMs have some).

For example, if you use i3, you'd add `exec xss-lock xsecurelock` to ~/.i3/config. Alternatively, if you launch everything using 'startx', then add `xss-lock xsecurelock &` somewhere in ~/.xinitrc.

Comment: Ok, I get it, thank you. I tried running `xss-lock xsecurelock &` in a terminal emulator (from the X11 session). Then, when I run `loginctl lock-session`, it works correctly.
However, if I run `xss-lock xsecurelock &` in ~/.xinitrc, and then run `loginctl lock-session` from the terminal emulator, nothing happens. `ps aux` confirms that in both cases it is running.

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Session_lock#Inactivity) `xss-lock` hangs because it waits for `DPMS signaling` in order to trigger.
As user 1686 said you need to put `&` after the command in your `~/.xinitrc` or `~/.xprofile` (whatever you use) in order for `xss-lock` not to hang (otherwise you might end up hanging your entire session).

If you want to lock manually, there is no point using `xss-lock`. You can use directly `xsecurelock` from a terminal or by binding this to a key depending on your DE/WM.

So it makes sense to use `xss-lock` for automatic locking due to inactivity for example. In order to do that you need to use `xset` as mentioned in the link I posted. Here is how I have set it up (I use LightDM's `dm-tool lock` command to lock the session).

```
~/.xinitrc
# Some other things ...

xset s on
xset s 300 # Signal after 5 minutes / 300 seconds of inactivity
xss-lock dm-tool lock &
# Your's would be xss-lock xsecurelock &
```

If I want to lock from terminal directly I just use `dm-tool lock` or set a keybinding in my WM's configuration to call `dm-tool lock`.

As you can see there is no `xss-lock` usage apart from locking due to inactivity